Is it possible to draw this picture without lifting the pen? (I actually want to hang string lights this way in a gazebo without doubling up)
Here is how I want to hang the lights.
I want to avoid going over any of the sections twice, if that's possible.  

See Euler Paths

I can't even figure out how to do it with TWO strings of lights and have the two plugs end up at the same outlet!

" want to avoid going over any of the sections twice, if that's possible." does this imply that I can't go over the same point twice?

No.  Your graph doesn't have a Eulerian path (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) - it has four vertices of odd degree.
Using less formal terminology, if there's no doubling up, then at each of the places where lines meet, except at the beginning and end of your path, you have to enter and leave the same number of times, so you should have an even number of lines coming in and out.     At the beginning and end of the path you can have an odd number of lines (except if the beginning and end are the same).
But you have four places where three lines meet (the four corners of the big rectangle) so you can't do it.
However if you're willing to go over either the topmost edge or the bottommost edge twice, then there are only two vertices of odd degree and you can find a path.
Alternately, there is a way to do the whole design with no doublings but with two strands of lights. One strand of lights covers all the internal diagonals and the top edge, and the other strand covers the left, right, and bottom edges.

This is not an answer but an attempt to offer the most efficient solution to the real-life problem that inspired the question.
While I believe it can't be drawn, though I don't have rigorous proof at hand (one might argue that the construction below hints at one), there is at least one way you can use a single cord to create it with only a single double-up .
We start by considering the pattern as if it is already created, and try to "unravel" it with the minimal number of double-ups. The steps are denoted $1,2,3,4$ and the only double up occurs at the $AB$ segment.


yes, in all the different ways I tried to figure this out, there is at a minimum one side that will need to be doubled up. But I am no math wiz :)

Since the four ‘odd’ junctions are the corners A, B, C, and D, then the doubled-up path must start and end at any two of those (with the string starting and ending at the other two).  The shortest of those paths are A–B and C–D, so either of those would give the least doubling-up.

As explained, you do not have an Euler path.
To make one, you must double up a connection between odd vertices. This is most efficiently done by doubling up either the top side or the bottom side.
To this end, consider this alternative.


The string would then have to start and end at the two bottom corners.  Another alternative would be to add similar lines to the bottom as well — then the string could start and end at any vertex.
